# How can I get the box (x,y,w,h) coordinates in the original image if I created the box on a down scaled image?

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing

I have a script where I use a sliding window to detect something in the picture. After every part of the image was checked I downscale it and I do the same again.

If I have a detection I return with the coordinates of the bounding box. `(x, y, width, height)`.

But what if I detected on a down scaled image, how can I return the *"real"* coordinates on the original image?

Here is part of my code so far:

```
scaledNumber = 0
detections = []
DOWNSCALE = 1.3

for imageScaled in pyramid_gaussian(image, downscale=DOWNSCALE):
    if imageScaled.shape[0] < MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[1] or imageScaled.shape[1] < MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[0]:
        break
    for (x1, y1, x2, y2, croppedImage) in slidingWindow(imageScaled, MIN_WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_STEP_SIZE):
        if croppedImage.shape[0] != MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[1] or croppedImage.shape[1] != MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[0]:
            continue


        HERE I DO THE DETECTION WITH the croppedImage

        detections.append((x1, y1, x1 + int(MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[0] * (DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber)),
                                   y1 + int(MIN_WINDOW_SIZE[1] * (DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber)), croppedImage))


    scaledNumber += 1
```

Comment: just upscale the coordinates, so multiply with you scaling factor.

Comment: multiply each with the factor: x, y, width, height

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments!

This is how I did it and I got really good results:

```
detections.append((int(x1 * DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber), int(y1 * DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber),
                                   int(x2 * DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber), int(y2 * DOWNSCALE ** scaledNumber),
                                   croppedImage))
```